# Displaying average rating from ratingbar in recycler view

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a method that should return the average rating for each item in my `RecyclerView`, but it keeps showing the overall rating for all of the ratings combined instead of just the rating that is specific to a row. I use

```
select AVG(rating_value) from rating where location_id = ?;
```

for the value for `Rating_table.GET_ALL_RATINGS`

```
public float getAvgRate(int locationID)
    {
        mDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(Rating_table.GET_ALL_RATINGS,
                new String[] {String.valueOf(locationID)});
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
            return cursor.getFloat(cursor.getPosition());
        cursor.close();
        mDatabase.close();
        return 0;
    }
```

Everything is stored correctly in my database, but it just is not displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you use

```
cursor.getFloat(0);
```

instead of

```
cursor.getFloat(cursor.getPosition());
```

In android developer

> getPosition()
>   Returns the current position of the cursor in the row set.
>
> getFloat(int columnIndex)
>   Returns the value of the requested column as a float.